# Raspbian, Java and GStreamer

Tags: java, gstreamer, raspbian

I have to generate a jar with eclipse on my mac, and use it on a Raspberry Pi (with Raspbian)

I use webcam-capture to take snapshoot with a usb webcam, with the driver-gstreamer. But, after all installations on the raspberry, I have an error when I launch the jar.

```
Exception in thread main java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'gstreamer-0.10': Native library (linux-arm/libgstreamer-0.10.so) not found in resource path ([file:/home/pi/Desktop/test.jar])
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:271)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
at com.sun.jna.Library.<init>(Library.java:147)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
at org.gstreamer.lowlevel.GNative.loadNativeLibrary(GNative.java:48)
at org.gstreamer.lowlevel.GNative.loadLibrary(GNative.java:45)
at org.gstreamer.lowlevel.GstNative.load(GstNative.java:42)
at org.gstreamer.lowlevel.GstNative.load(GstNative.java:39)
at org.gstreamer.Gst.<clinit>(Gst.java:59)
at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.gstreamer.GStreamerDriver.init(GStreamerDriver.java:90)
at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.gstreamer.GStreamerDriver.<init>(GStreamerDriver.java:49)
at CamFloat.<clinit>(CamFloat.java:24)
```

gstreamer-0.10 is installed, with

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer-0.10
```

How can I launch the jar file with the native library? And where can I find it?
It is mabye a stupid question, but I really don’t understand how it should work.

Thank you for reading and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Look into the jar (zip format) for the correct .so and create an alias with `ln -s`;`linux-arm/libgstreamer-0.10.so`: not so experienced though

Comment: I found the linux-arm folder in the unzip jar file, and the `.so` to link. But how can I make a new jar from the unzip folder? I've try to use the `jar cmf` command, but It dosn't work.

Comment: using zip on the unzip folder would be less problematic, as long as no checksum/directory index was used. The m is maybe too much, specifies a manifest file; see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html